# Using Join query with multiple tables to order in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following tables,

**1. EmpRegDet**

**2. EmpPlan**

**3. Alert**

**My code**

```
return (from job in _db.Jobs
        join employerregdetails in _db.EmployerRegistrationDetails on job.OrganizationId equals employerregdetails.EmployerId into e
        join ep in _db.EmployerPlans on **emp.PlanId** equals ep.EmployerPlanId
        join alr in _db.AlertsDones on ep.Alerts equals alr.AlertsSent
        from emp in e.DefaultIfEmpty()
        orderby job.OrganizationId != -1 descending, job.OrganizationId != null descending
        orderby job.OrganizationId != -1 descending, emp.EmployerId == job.OrganizationId descending, job.CreatedDate descending
        select job);
```

Here I have an error `emp.planId`. how to check this? Please help me..

Comment: What is `emp` variable?

Comment: What *error*?! You have to be more specific.

Comment: Actually i assign `into` any table in join query. i cant use that variable some other.. how to solve that.. it is showing an error `the name __ in the scope of the left side of the equals`..

Comment: I edit my question also.. assign the `emp` value